# Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i am trying to add a class to  but it doesnt work

```
<script>
    var url = document.location.pathname;
    debugger;
    if(url === '/about.php') {
        $('.about').addClass('active');
        //document.getElementsByClassName('about')[0].addClass('active');
        console.log(url);
    }
//important part start
    if(url === '/index.php') {
        $('.homee').addClass('active');
        document.getElementsByClassName('homee')[0].addClass('active');
        console.log(url); 
    } 
//important part end
    if(url === '/sch.php') {
        $('.schedule').addClass('active');
        //document.getElementsByClassName('schedule')[0].addClass('active');
        console.log(url);
    }
    if(url === '/images.php') {
        $('.gallery').addClass('active');
        //document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].addClass('active');
        console.log(url);
    }
    if(url ===  '/videos.php') {
        $('.gallery').addClass('active');
    }
    console.log(url);

    </script>

<ul class="menu" >
    <li class='homee' ><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
</ul>
```

as you can see i tryed 2 methods and $('.homee').addClass('active'); didnt say Cannot read property 'addClass' of undefined but it still didnt add the class

Comment: Should “homee” be “home”?

Comment: yes but i already have class and id home for something else so i just added another e

Comment: Okay, just checking. Because the HTML did not have a class named “homee” you would have gotten that error. Anyway, glad you found the solution. I’ve made that same mistake a few times. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running the script before the HTML has been populated - at the time the parser gets to the `$('.homee').addClass('active');` line, the `<li class='homee' >` hasn't been created yet, since as you can see, the element is *below* the script.

Wrap your whole script in a function that fires once the document has been parsed:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var url = document.location.pathname;
    debugger;
    if(url === '/about.php') {
      $('.about').addClass('active');
      //document.getElementsByClassName('about')[0].addClass('active');
      console.log(url);
    }
    //important part start
    if(url === '/index.php') {
      $('.homee').addClass('active');
      document.getElementsByClassName('homee')[0].addClass('active');
      console.log(url); 
    } 
    //important part end
    if(url === '/sch.php') {
      $('.schedule').addClass('active');
      //document.getElementsByClassName('schedule')[0].addClass('active');
      console.log(url);
    }
    if(url === '/images.php') {
      $('.gallery').addClass('active');
      //document.getElementsByClassName('gallery')[0].addClass('active');
      console.log(url);
    }
    if(url ===  '/videos.php') {
      $('.gallery').addClass('active');
    }
    console.log(url);
  });
</script>
```

Even better, put the script in a separate file and give it the `defer` attribute:

```
<script src="myscript.js" defer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code if you want to use JQuery

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
       // your code here
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

[.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) is a jQuery method. If you want to add the class using the plain javaScript you can write:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('homee')[0].classList.add('active')
```

For documentation see [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('homee')[0].classList.add('active')

});
```

```css
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu" >
    <li class='homee' ><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
</ul>
```